# IOS my app version number doesn't change

Tags: ios, version, version-numbering

I want to send a new update for my app , so I changed my app version number to be 2.1

[image: as my image says]

but it doesn't change , when I try to submit it to app store , I get an error which says that my kcfbundleversionkey (something like that :P ) is 1.0.1 which is the previous version on my iTunes connect , whats wrong ?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

Two lines above the row you have selected is the bundle version that the App Store looks at.  Change that number.

Comment: it's 2.0 , but it says 1.0.1 , I don't see any 1.0.1 in my info.plist

Answer (score 0):

it's okay I solved it , I reinstalled Xcode and everything went well , weird bug though!!